# Is there just one IRC NickServ in the world, or does each IRC network have it's own NickServ?

Tags: irc

Is there just one IRC NickServ in the world, that all IRC networks use?

Or does each IRC **network** (e.g. FreeNode, GIMPNet, etc.) have it's own NickServ?

In other words do I need at least one pair of credentials (username + password), or at least multiple pairs of credentials, one for each different network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there just one IRC NickServ in the world

Nope.  It's per-network.

IRC is an extremely basic protocol that basically forwards text between a bunch of users TCP connections, with a few basic concepts like nicknames, channels, modes for nicknames and channels, and little else.

Classical IRC does not ...

- remember anything posted in a channel
- remember anything about a user once the user's TCP connection disconnects from the server
- remember anything about a channel once all users leave it or become disconnected, including who owns it, the topic, people who are authorized to be channel operator, etc.
- have the notion of accounts, profiles, presence.  The nickname and the reverse DNS of your IP is mostly what identifies you.

So if you want those things, those have to be implemented as  a layer "above" IRC, and that's what NickServ, ChanServ, etc. are.  There's software like `atheme-services` and others - and these work by acting as a bot and logging into IRC like a user would.

Typically the IRC server itself has support for these services and will give the bots running these names special privileges.

Agreed-upon standards for the special service names exist, as well as their behavior.  So that's why you see NickServ and ChanServ everywhere, but they're not overall global to every IRC network, they are just servicing the network they sit on.